# How can I fetch a list of games and DLC for a user via Steam's API?

Tags: steam

We're trying to figure out how to fetch a list of all games and DLC owned by a Steam user using that user's Steam ID.

There is [a method for fetching a list of games for an account](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API#GetOwnedGames_.28v0001.29) by using the Steam Web API but this does not include any DLC. Another option is to use the [public community XML data provided by Steam](http://steamcommunity.com/id/pewdie/games?tab=all&xml=1).

The problem with this is first of all that this information can be made public/non-public so we can't be sure to get the whole picture. Also this way of fetching data is [flagged as deprecated by Steam](https://partner.steamgames.com/documentation/community_data).

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this using supported Steam APIs?

Comment: I assume you've asked on the [WebAPI forum](http://steamcommunity.com/groups/steamworks/discussions/8)? The full documentation for the Web API seems to be hidden behind a login wall, so it seems unlikely you're going to get a better response here than there.

Comment: thanks Josh, I will post the question over there as well :)

Comment: Did you ever happen to find a solution to this?

Comment: Pretty sure that information is NDAd.

Answer (score 6):

I'd like to mention that there are also other ways to get the accurate DLC data instead of using the API.

For example, Steamdb extension gets owned games and DLC info from http://store.steampowered.com/dynamicstore/userdata/

It shows lists of item ids related to the user who is logged in at the moment. Those lists are:

- rgWishlist
- rgOwnedPackages
- rgOwnedApps
- rgPackagesInCart
- rgAppsInCart
- rgRecommendedTags
- rgIgnoredApps
- rgIgnoredPackages

I find this way of getting info about everything the user owns to be much more precise than others.

**The main downside is that dynamicstore data is not public**, and can be accessed only by the person it belongs to (and clientside scripts of course). Which makes it not that easily accessible as Web API, but still useful in some cases (like with steamdb extension, where the DLCs info is really important).

Comment: So this is separate from the previously mentioned API?  Can you elaborate about the difference?  (Two APIs, accessibility, language, or what?)

Comment: I'm not really sure what exactly is that feature that I described, I couldn't find it documented anywhere, just saw it's being used by steamdb extension. Probably it's something the Steam itself using to add storefront icons "On wishlist", "In library", etc.
The main difference between this way and using Steam Web API is accessibility (dynamicstore is not public), and that dynamicstore way lists not only owned games, but DLC too. And I've heard that it's even more precise than the community XML data.
Finally, I think it's the only known way to get a list of ignored game ids.